# Problem with the connection of an android studio project to my Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My application crashes when I register the user, and no data is added to the database, but authentication works. I changed url with my url from my database, but without result.

```
private void createAccount(String mail, String pass) {
        final Firebase myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://locationtaxi-3c86d.firebaseio.com/Users"); //https://ipark-e243b.firebaseio.com/Users

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mail) || TextUtils.isEmpty(pass)) {
            Toast.makeText(DriverRegistration.this, "Please enter username and password.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            progress.show();
            progress.setMessage("Signing in....");
            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(mail, pass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        progress.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(DriverRegistration.this, "Error signing up", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(DriverRegistration.this, "Sign up successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        UserProfileChangeRequest displayName = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder().
                                setDisplayName(newUser.getUsername()).build();
                        auth.getCurrentUser().updateProfile(displayName).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(DriverRegistration.this,
                                            "Could not set the display name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        myFirebaseRef.child(newUser.getUsername()).setValue(newUser); //ligne 366 error
                        progress.dismiss();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(DriverRegistration.this, LoginPage.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

The error message is

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ucsd.cse110fa16.group14.ipark, PID: 2613
    com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to parse to snapshot
        at com.firebase.client.Firebase.setValueInternal(Firebase.java:347)
        at com.firebase.client.Firebase.setValue(Firebase.java:238)
        at ucsd.cse110fa16.group14.ipark.DriverRegistration$9.onComplete(DriverRegistration.java:366)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

My database on Firebase:

[image]

Comment: you provide the read and write permission for the database check this if your not provide.

Comment: You're using a version of the Firebase SDK that is over 3½ years old. While that isn't necessarily the cause of the problem, I **highly** recommend first upgrading to a recent version so we can rule it out as a possible cause.

Comment: If the problem still occurs after that, update your question with the updated code and stack trace. Also make sure that it then includes how you declare and initialize `newUser`, as we have no idea about that from the code you shared now.

Comment: how can I upgrade the firebase sdk ?